# Does copying cookies from one pc to other makes Gmail believe that the other device is not a new device login?

Tags: cookies

Each time I login into a new device either Gmail or Facebook login, it send a notification to my mobile saying a login is detected in a new device stating the device name or OS name.

I am curious to know if it is possible to copy cookies from one computer to other so that if I now login into this new system then Gmail or Facebook should not know that this device is a new device and it should not send notification to my phone a new login is detected.

If user id and password for that particular service is not an issue.

Comment: Just try it. You can use VMs if you do not have access to a 2nd computer.

Comment: That would surprise me. Facebook & google send me notifications when I login from different devices and those include browser used, operating system and IP address together with approximate location (which is usually quite far off for me). So it's highly likely that they take into account the browser and OS used (not the IP I think since almost noone has a static IPv4 addresses nowadays )